# How to run xaction file in the background from CDE

Tags: background, pentaho, pentaho-cde, xaction

I am trying to run an action sequence from a dashboard in Pentaho 5.2. I usually press button with js function *window.open("path/name.xaction")* which runs the action sequence and (logically) opens a window with *Action succes* message. 
But I want to run the action sequence without opening a new window and stay at the dashboard. 
I managed to run the  action sequence  and redirect the page to the dashboard again. It works, but it's not the nicest.
I would like to run the action sequence in the background, it seems like a better idea.

How to run *.xaction file in the background from CDE? (Or how to run something in the background by using javascript?)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ajax call from the dashboard page and call the xaction file.!! It will run the xaction at the background without refreshing the page.

check the below link:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp